# My API works fine when tested with Postman or ThunderClient but when i integrated swagger it's not showing any parameters

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

[Image 1 showing no parameters in swagger UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hpnEY.png)

[Image 2 showing registration endpoint upon registration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHn5n.png)

[Image 3 showing login endpoint upon login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/huODI.png)

## Below are my code snippets in views.py

```
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.generics import GenericAPIView
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from account.serializers import (
    SendPasswordResetEmailSerializer,
    UserChangePasswordSerializer,
    UserLoginSerializer,
    UserPasswordResetSerializer,
    UserProfileSerializer,
    UserRegistrationSerializer,
)
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
from account.renderers import UserRenderer
from rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens import RefreshToken
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
from drf_yasg.utils import swagger_auto_schema
```

## Generate Token Manually

```
def get_tokens_for_user(user):
    refresh = RefreshToken.for_user(user)
    return {
        "refresh": str(refresh),
        "access": str(refresh.access_token),
    }
```

```
class UserRegistrationView(GenericAPIView):
    renderer_classes = [UserRenderer]

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = UserRegistrationSerializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = serializer.save()
        token = get_tokens_for_user(user)
        return Response(
            {"token": token, "msg": "Registration Successful"},
            status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED,
        )
```

## UserLoginView

```
class UserLoginView(APIView):
    renderer_classes = [UserRenderer]

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = UserLoginSerializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        email = serializer.data.get("email")
        password = serializer.data.get("password")
        user = authenticate(email=email, password=password)
```

## UserLoginView cont'd

```
        if user is not None:
            token = get_tokens_for_user(user)
            return Response(
                {"token": token, "msg": "Login Success"}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK
            )
        else:
            return Response(
                {"errors": {"non_field_errors": ["Email or Password is not Valid"]}},
                status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND,
            )
```

## UserProfileView

```
class UserProfileView(APIView):
    renderer_classes = [UserRenderer]
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = UserProfileSerializer(request.user)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

#UserChangePasswordView

```
class UserChangePasswordView(APIView):
    renderer_classes = [UserRenderer]
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = UserChangePasswordSerializer(
            data=request.data, context={"user": request.user}
        )
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        return Response(
            {"msg": "Password Changed Successfully"}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK
        )
```

## SendPasswordResetEmailView

```
class SendPasswordResetEmailView(APIView):
    renderer_classes = [UserRenderer]

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = SendPasswordResetEmailSerializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        return Response(
            {"msg": "Password Reset link send. Please check your Email"},
            status=status.HTTP_200_OK,
        )
```

## UserPasswordResetView

```
class UserPasswordResetView(APIView):
    renderer_classes = [UserRenderer]

    def post(self, request, uid, token, format=None):
        serializer = UserPasswordResetSerializer(
            data=request.data, context={"uid": uid, "token": token}
        )
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        return Response(
            {"msg": "Password Reset Successfully"}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't make sure, but I have a reason. Maybe it might be about your views.py. You wrote the serializer class only in the post function. Thus, swagger couldn't recognize your serializer. Can you try this one?

```
class UserLoginView(APIView):
    renderer_classes = [UserRenderer]
    serializer_class = UserLoginSerializer

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = UserLoginSerializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        email = serializer.data.get("email")
        password = serializer.data.get("password")
        user = authenticate(email=email, password=password)
```